# square rotate in css grid creates gaps

Tags: html, css, css-grid, css-transforms

Rotating a square div inside a css grid create gaps. Why?

Here is a simple example:

```css
div {
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin:0;
    display:block;
}

.square{ 
    background: skyBlue;
}

.rotate{
    transform:rotate(180deg);
}

#grid {
    display: grid;
    height:100vmin;
    width: 100vmin;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);

    background: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id=grid>
     <div style="grid-row: 1; grid-column:2">normal</div>
     <div class="square" style="grid-row: 2; grid-column:2"></div>
     <div class="square" style="grid-row: 3; grid-column:2"></div>
     <div class="square" style="grid-row: 4; grid-column:2"></div>


     <div style="grid-row: 1; grid-column:4">rotated (180deg)</div>
     <div class="square rotate" style="grid-row: 2; grid-column:4"></div>
     <div class="square rotate" style="grid-row: 3; grid-column:4"></div>
     <div class="square rotate" style="grid-row: 4; grid-column:4"></div>
</div>
```

In the snipped code, one can see **small gaps between the right column grids**.
Only the rotated grids apear to have gap between them, while the left column of "normal" (not rotated) grids seems smooth.

**Why are gaps occuring after rotation?
How can I fix it?**

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260776/8620333

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether the thin lines are seen can depend on the browser/screen/zoom level.

For example on Chrome I zoomed on your snippet and the line came and went.

I think the problem is like a rounding error/edge effect. The system is trying to work out how to deal with part pixels - in this case with the height of a blue element being a % of a grid space which is obtained by calculation and then rotated. It's not come up with an exact integer every time. On modern screens it has to convert as one CSS pixel can be several screen pixels. Sometimes some screen pixels 'get left behind'. (Notice that the thin line is very thin, not as much as one CSS pixel).

Looking at your code a hacky way round is to increase the size of the rotated div by a couple of pixels and reset its position accordingly. This may or may not be suitable for your real life situation.

```css
div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}

.square {
  background: skyBlue;
}

.rotate {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

#grid {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vmin;
  width: 100vmin;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: auto;
}

.rotate {
  height: calc(100% + 2px);
  width: calc(100% + 2px);
  margin-top: -1px;
  margin-left: -1px;
}
```

```html
<div id=grid>
  <div style="grid-row: 1; grid-column:2">normal</div>
  <div class="square" style="grid-row: 2; grid-column:2"></div>
  <div class="square" style="grid-row: 3; grid-column:2"></div>
  <div class="square" style="grid-row: 4; grid-column:2"></div>


  <div style="grid-row: 1; grid-column:4">rotated (180deg)</div>
  <div class="square rotate" style="grid-row: 2; grid-column:4"></div>
  <div class="square rotate" style="grid-row: 3; grid-column:4"></div>
  <div class="square rotate" style="grid-row: 4; grid-column:4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well explained and great hack! Thanks!